# Parse credit card statement

Tags: parsing, banking

I'd love to develop my custom software to monitor my monthly expenses, but I'm struggling on the first step. Rather than having to input any expense into a big spreadsheet every now and then, I'd like to parse my banking credit card statement, to get as much information as possible.
From the most important to the least, here's what I'd like to know about each expense: **price, category** (food / travel / home...), **date, store name, location**.

However I don't know how to guess the category / shop corresponding to a given statement. If understand correctly, there is no real convention for the text, though most often it's the name of the owning company, which might not be the name of the store.

```
05/06    CB SAPPORO     10      -> 10$, Restaurant, 05/06, _name_of_the_restaurant_
```

Tbh I'm surprised that I could find anything online, it seems like something many people might want to do. Is there any kind of standard database, or existing library to do that ? How do the services which do that do it ?
Any help / redirection would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: There are different formats for banking statements (such as MT940 or CAMT). Which one are you trying to parse?

Comment: I can download the statement in CSV, OFX or PDF, which do no seem to meet any standard, however it is pretty similar to MT940. The biggest question is how to extract information from the description of the expense?